# Why does this not always return false?

Tags: java

This is a problem from codingbat:

Given an array of ints, return true if one of the first 4 elements in the array is a 9. The array length may be less than 4.

```
public boolean arrayFront9(int[] nums) {
int i = 0;

  for(i=0;i<4; i++) {
  if(nums[i]==9) return true;

  }
  return false;

}
```

an example output:

arrayFront9({1, 2, 9, 3, 4}) will return true.

Why does this not always return false? If the for loop is ran first and returns true for the 3rd index but then false for the 4th(last index checked), shouldn't the for loop return false? Or does the loop exit after finding a 9? Also, there is a "return false;" line after the for loop, why does this not automatically overwrite whatever value the for loop outputted? My understanding was that Java executes the code one line at a time so it would read the return false and return false no matter what since it's the last line of code.

Comment: The cool exits once `return` is called.

Comment: Why did you think of it as a problem? if you read the syntax of the commands you will understand it. Although I think you already understand it since you knew that with the example you gave will return true. the answers given below are good explanation for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

When a `return` statement is executed, the current method is immediately exited.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the `for` loop reaches the 3rd element in the `array` which is 9 , it will `return
 true` and it will `break` the `for` loop and stop executing what's after it